# How can you add a character or symbol to a formula?

Tags: formula

My formula is generating the quarter as a single numeral.
So the result is either 1,2,3 or 4.
I want to have it show as Q1, Q2, or Q4.
I can't just put the Q in front of the formula FLOOR((MONTH(CloseDate)-1)/3) + 1
I tried 'Q' etc.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're returning "text" (and that's important, it has to return text), you can use:

```
"Q" & TEXT(FLOOR((MONTH(CloseDate)-1)/3)+1)
```

Comment: Same result as Willards below, thanks though.

Comment: @Miklr Make sure the formula's return type is text. This formula works *verbatim* in my developer org.

Answer (score 1):

Is your formula field of type text?  If so you should be able to just add the Q in front of there:
`'Q' & TEXT(FLOOR((MONTH(CloseDate)-1)/3) + 1)`

Comment: Number field but even trying text I get errors on both for your suggestion. Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Text, received Number
Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Text, received Number (Related field: Formula), thanks though.

Comment: Sorry, use the '&' symbol instead, as in sfdcfox's solution